# Unity Build to Android Phone isn't "clean"

Tags: android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, build

I want to build my game to my smartphone for testing.
It worked quite fine yesterday. But after todays build it's kinda weird.
I start with 60 money (and thats a quite random number) and I have a Player Skin and another Skin is selected.
But i havent changed anything in this source code so it couldnt be.
As well i have 2 achievements unlocked at the beginning...
I work with Playfab to save some files, but they should reload after build.

You guys have any ideas? I mean is there a way to really do a new build, no datas saved?

Answer (score 1):

Some files are saved in the cloud so resetting playprefs would not solve the issue. You either clean your cloud or go to your phone settings -> Apps -> find your app -> Clean data (or cache). After you clear all data, you're good to go. Remember: this only happens to you. If someone else install your game, they will start fresh. So it only happens to you. :)

Comment: okay thanks but i deinstall the game everytime i build and this doesnt work.. i tried to clear the cache but doesnt work as well.. How can i delete cloud safes? And if i do playerprefs.delteall(); it works on my pc in the unity project, so everything is clean after but for my smartphone this doesnt work as well...

Answer (score 0):

Ok
I had to delete/reset the cache AND the storage (on my phone)
I dont know why but in a way it saved something into the storage.

So far it worked just by delete the app and rebuild but now i have to empty them as well :(